# Is there a proof for L'Hôpital's Rule for limits approaching infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

*L'Hopital's Rule* states that:

*For two differentiable functions $f$ and $g$, where $g'(x)\neq 0$, such that*

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=0$$

$$\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=0$$

We can say that:

$$\lim_{x\to a} {f(x)\over g(x)}= \lim_{x\to a} {f'(x)\over g'(x)}\\ $$

**NOTE: If you already know the proof and don't want to read all this, skip all the way down to $\blacksquare_{1.1}$**

**PROOF 1.1:**

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Also, assume $g'(x)\neq 0$ on $(a,b)$ and $g(b)\neq g(a).\\$

**Proposition 1.1.1:** *There exists some point $c$ within the open interval $(a,b)$ such that:*

${f'(c)\over g'(c)} = {{f(b) - f(a)}\over {g(b) - g(a)}}$

*Proof 1.1.1* $\quad \triangleright$

Let $$\space h(x)= f(x)-f(a) - {{f(b) - f(a)}\over {g(b) - g(a)}}\cdot (g(x)-g (a))\\$$

By simply substituting values we can clearly see that $h(a)=h(b)=0$. 
Now because $f(a)$, $f(b)$, $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ are constants, we can therefore say that much like $f$ and $g$,  $h$ is also continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b).\\$

If we differentiate  $h$ w.r.t. $x$, we get the following:

$$h'(x) = f'(x) - g'(x)\cdot {{f(b) - f(a)}\over {g(b) - g(a)}}\\$$

Using *Rolle's Theorem* (which I porpusely won't prove as the question is long enough as it is) we can say that *there exists a $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $h'(c)=0$*

Thus we can say that

$0 = f'(c) - g'(c)\cdot {{f(b) - f(a)}\over {g(b) - g(a)}} $

Hence showing us that

${f'(c)\over g'(c)} = {{f(b) - f(a)}\over {g(b) - g(a)}}$

$$\blacksquare_{1.1.1}$$

$\triangleleft \\$

Remember that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= \lim_{x\to a} g(x)=0$.

Where $a$ is finite.

We also said $g(x)\neq 0$.

Therefore we'll Let

$L:= \lim_{x\to a} {f'(x)\over g'(x)} \\$

We're also going to define the functions $F$ and $G$.

$F(x) = f(x) \Longrightarrow x\neq a$
$F(x) = 0 \Longrightarrow x = a$

Similarly

$G(x) = g(x) \Longrightarrow x\neq a$
$G(x) = 0 \Longrightarrow x = a$

Because $F$ and $G$ are defined at $x=a$, they are continuous at $a$. (Unlike $f$ and $g$)

This means that for $x>a$, the functions  $F$ and $G$ are differentiable on the open interval  $(a,x)$ and continuous on the closed interval $[a,x]. \\$

Using what we showed in *Proof 1.1.1*,  we can state the following equality to be true:

$${F'(c)\over G'(c)} = {{F(x) - F(a)}\over {G(x) - G(a)}}$$

Due to the fact that $F(a)=0$ and $G(a)=0$, we can thus say

$${F'(c)\over G'(c)} = {{F(x)}\over {G(x)}}$$

Now since $c$ is within the interval $(a,x)$, we can say $a<c<x$.

This means that

$x\rightarrow {a^+} \Longrightarrow c\rightarrow {a^+}$

Therefore because $F$ and $G$ are simply the functions $f$ and $g$ respectively where $x=a$ is defined. It's correct for us to then say

$$\lim_{x\to a^+} {f(x)\over g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a^+} {F(x)\over G(x)} = \lim_{c\to a^+} {F'(c)\over G'(c)} $$

Also

$$\lim_{c\to a^+} {F'(c)\over G'(c)} = \lim_{c\to a^+} {f'(c)\over g'(c)}\\$$

If we notice...

$$L:=\lim_{c\to a^+} {f'(c)\over g'(c)}= \lim_{x\to a^+} {f'(x)\over g'(x)}$$

Hence showing us that

$$\lim_{x\to a} {f(x)\over g(x)}= \lim_{x\to a} {f'(x)\over g'(x)} $$

$$\blacksquare_{1.1}\\$$

Isn't this only true when $\lim_{x\to a} {f(x)\over g(x)}={0\over 0}$?

How would you prove $\lim_{x\to a} {f(x)\over g(x)}= \lim_{x\to a} {f'(x)\over g'(x)} $ for limits such as:

$\lim_{x\to a} {f(x)\over g(x)}={\pm\infty\over \pm\infty}$?

Comment: For $\infty/\infty$ we can write $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\frac{1}{g(x)}}{\frac{1}{f(x)}}$ which is on the form $0/0$. Applying L'Hopital to this we get $\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim\frac{g'(x)}{f'(x)}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)^2$ so if $\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = a$ then $\lim \frac{f'}{g'} = a$.

Comment: @Winther - Ahh I see it now... I've been looking everywhere for this but couldn't find it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You can't a priori assume that $ \lim f(x)/g(x)$ exists.  You want to show that it follows from $ \lim f'(x)/g'(x) = L$ existing.

Comment: Limits don't approach anything. They either exist or don't. And if they exist, they don't move around and approach something.

Comment: @zhw. Yeah I think I should have worded the question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f(x),g(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to a+$ and

$$ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L.$$

For any $\epsilon > 0 $ there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ such that if $a < x < a + \delta_1$ then

$$\left|\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}-L \right|< C\epsilon,$$

with $C = [2(1+|L|)]^{-1}$.

Fix $x_1 < a + \delta_1.$ By the MVT there exists $c$ such that

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}h(x):=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\frac{1- \frac{f(x_1)}{f(x)}}{1-\frac{g(x_1)}{g(x)}}=\frac{f(x) - f(x_1)}{g(x)-g(x_1)}= \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}.$$

Since $x < c < x_1 < a + \delta_1 $ we have

$$C\epsilon > \left|\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}-L \right| = \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}h(x)-L \right|.$$

Hence, using the reverse triangle inequality

$$C\epsilon > \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}h(x)-Lh(x) + L h(x)-L \right|\geqslant \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L\right||h(x)| - |L| |h(x)-1|, $$

and

$$ \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L\right||h(x)| < C\epsilon + |L| |h(x)-1|.$$

Note that $\lim_{x \to a+}h(x) = 1$. Hence, there exists $\delta_2 > 0$ such that for $a < x < a + \delta_2$ we have  $|h(x) - 1| < C\epsilon$ and $|h(x)| > 1/2.$

Whence, if $a < x < a +  \min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ then

$$\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L\right| < 2(1 + |L|)C\epsilon = \epsilon.$$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{x \to a+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to a+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} .$$

Comment: You Sir/Madam have shown that I have a looong way to go (still in first year Mathematics). I must learn more!!! Thank you for inspiring me :).

Comment: @MaxEchendu: You did well on the $0/0$ case.  The $\infty/\infty$ case is just a bit more intricate.

Comment: Thank you. I'm certainly going to be taking several more trips to the library until I can say I'm up there in terms of knowledge.

Comment: Important fact: We only need assume $g\to \infty$ (very much  like Stolz Cesaro), no assumption on limiting behavior of $f$ is needed